# counting rows by sampling in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of over 1000 lines, where I want to read values from 10 rows at a time. eg - I want to calculate the number of times Logic is ***1*** for the first 10 rows, then for the next 10 rows and so on.

| Time | Logic |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 997 | 1 |
| 998 | 0 |
| 999 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need an array, use the underlying numpy array:

```
df['Logic'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,10).sum(1)
```

output:

```
array([8, 3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 3, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4,
       5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 6,
       6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6,
       6, 8, 4, 4, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6,
       5, 5, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 2, 2, 4, 6, 1])
```

With pandas, you could also use `groupby` + `sum`:

```
df.groupby(df.index//10)['Logic'].sum()
```

or, if you don't have a range index:

```
import numpy as np
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)['Logic'].sum()
```

Example:

```
# reproducible input
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(1000)+1,
                   'Logic': np.random.choice([0,1], 1000)})

# calculation
N = 10
out = df.groupby(df.index//N)['Logic'].sum()
```

output:

```
0     8
1     3
2     6
3     6
4     7
     ..
95    2
96    2
97    4
98    6
99    1
```